# What is preventing some of the content from an Invoke-WebRequest showing?

Tags: powershell, web-scraping, powershell-5.0, invoke-webrequest

I am trying to get some acsii art characters directly from a webpage. You can navigate to the page using the following URL.

http://patorjk.com/software/taag/#p=display&f=Acrobatic&t=A

If you go to that page you will see a rendering of the character A using the Acrobatic font.

> ```
>          o         
>         <|>        
>         / \        
>       o/   \o      
>      <|__ __|>     
>      /       \     
>    o/         \o   
>   /v           v\  
>  />             <\
> ```

Using the following code nets me most of the page.

```
$fontUrlTemplate = "http://patorjk.com/software/taag/#p=display&f={0}&t={1}"
$fontName = [uri]::EscapeUriString("Acrobatic")
$character = "A"

$fontUrl = $fontUrlTemplate -f $fontName, $character
$webResult = Invoke-WebRequest $fontUrl 
$webResult.Content
```

However when I inspect the Content the actual result I am looking for is missing.

```
...
<div id="maincontent" >
    <div id="outputFigDisplay" ></div>
</div>
...
```

There should be something like this in there

```
<pre id="taag_output_text" style="float:left;" class="fig" contenteditable="true">...</pre>
```

I am sure there is a server side reason for this but I would like to better understand and, if possible, mitigate it. I have tried mucking around with `-ContentType` and `-UserAgent` but it didn't change anything

Comment: That's because the contents in the `outputFigDisplay` div are calculated and painted after the page has loaded by [a piece of javascript](http://patorjk.com/software/taag/js/main.js?2017.01.01) in your browser

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Thanks. So I guess then I cannot do it this way.. IE Com object maybe... even though that sounds horrible.

Comment: Which means I found a dupe for this...